# Modify aggfunctions in pivot_tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

How can I combine two or more aggfunctions in a pandas pivot table?

I want to do something like:

```
pt = pandas.pivot_table(data, index=['Name'], values=['Grades'], aggfunc=[np.max - np.min])
```

To get the difference between the max and the min.

Likewise, is there any way to modify the aggfunc with a constant? Say doing something like:

```
...aggfunc=[np.max - 0.5])
```

(I know all of this could be done by manipulating the underlying data. But this would be a lot easier)

Comment: pandas.pivot_table(data, index=['Name'], values=['Grades'], aggfunc=np.max)-0.5?

Comment: In your first case you could do: `aggfunc=np.ptp` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html

Comment: Thanks both, those worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any Python function to the parameter aggfunc of [pandas.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html), from the documentation:

> aggfunc : function, list of functions, dict, default numpy.mean

As an example, for your first case, you could do:

**Setup**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name': ['bob', 'alice', 'mary', 'tom', 'bob', 'alice', 'mary', 'tom'], 'Grades': [10, 9, 8, 8, 7, 5, 6, 8]})
```

**Code**

```
result = pd.pivot_table(data, index=['Name'], values=['Grades'], aggfunc=lambda x: np.max(x) - np.min(x))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
       Grades
Name         
alice       4
bob         3
mary        2
tom         0
```